# Add back button in toolbar Android Fragment

Tags: android, menu

from some day I am working on a simple app. I have added a series of fragments and I would add back button in toolbar: https://ibb.co/93LBB3b

Someone could help me to understand how to do that?

Here, code of fragment:

```js
public class FragmentClothingCategory extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clothing_category, container, false);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where did you put the toolbar in the Activity or Fragment? also, are you using jetpack navigation architecture or not?

Comment: Hi, I put the toolbar in the MainActivity. Yes, I am using jetpack navigation architecture.

Comment: You want to replace that navigation to back button?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine yeah, I confirm.

Comment: Is that a back button or a hamburger? If hamburger, you can make your activity a DrawerActivity.

Comment: @KristyWelsh thank you for your message. I solved it :)